# Vue.js use prop like method name

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I've got this in `vue.js 2.0`:

```
export default {
    props:['context', 'service'],

    methods: {
        isSubscribed(context) {
            return context.subscriptions_count == 1;
        },

        subscribe(context) {
            this.service.subscribe(context.slug)
                .then(() => context.subscriptions_count = 1);
        },

        unSubscribe(context) {
            this.service.unSubscribe(context.slug)
                .then(() => context.subscriptions_count = 0);
        },
    }
```

This ^ is not working. How could I use `service` like a method name?

Thanks

Comment: Hey Jamie, your code actually looks ok, this.service is the way to use the service prop, can you share your component calling method? like: <my-component : service="serviceVar"></my-component>

Comment: @GerardoRosciano  hi, it looks like this: ```<subscription :context="message" service="MessageSubscriptionService"></subscription>
```

Comment: This is my error: ```Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'subscribe' of undefined at VueComponent.subscribe```

Comment: service should be :service because it's a dynamic property, test that and let us know.

Comment: @GerardoRosciano thanks that works